# Host key verification failed. Lost connection in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have two servers (AWS-Ubuntu), one is for Devops in which I have installed Jenkins. And in another server I have a dev server. I have built code in the Jenkins server and need to transfer my built files to the dev server.

Added (jenkins)id_rsa.pub key to dev server, restarted SSH service:

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/Angular
npm install
cd ${WORKSPACE}/node
npm install
cd ${WORKSPACE}/Angular
npm run build
```

```
scp -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project123/Angular/dist/* ubuntu@172.31.14.41:/var/
```

I expect to transfer files from Jenkins instance to dev server but I am getting this error:

```
scp -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project123/Angular/dist/openwifi ubuntu@172.31.45.66:/var/www/html/jenkinsdev/Angular/
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Host key verification failed error occurs when you try to ssh/scp using the wrong username.
username should be same which is used for establishing ssh. 
If above does not help then check the ssh keys are not corrupted or changed for that user.